# How can I make a two voltage source, 4-layer PCB in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I would like to make 2 different voltage sources on one layer (layer 15).
In the picture, the left rectangular area is a 5V polygon and the right one is 12 volts.

Is it possible? How much distance should be between the two voltages?

[image: Schemetic]

Answer (score 1):

Spacing isn't important with such a close voltage difference. 0.3mm should be more than enough although I would go larger just because. It makes a nice visual distinction between board areas when it's larger.

I had 5mm between 3.3V and 120V on one my board, and about 0.5mm between 15V and 120V in some places (which was probably too small to be safe, but it was a special gate-drive circuit and was isolated from the user) but still encountered no issues. If you want to use official standards the term you need to Google is "PCB creepage distance".

I assume that's an H-bridge? I guess there's a chance something could spark over if the inductive kick was large enough but you should have flyback diodes anyways to deal with that (or the MOSFET body diode but that is nowhere near as good).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.  With Eagle, if my memory serves me correctly, you make a polygon and attach it to the net.  It should then automatically connect to the pads & vias it's supposed to connect to, and refrain from connecting to the others.

@Toor's comments on spacing are quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, isolation isn't a big deal here.

If you want the isolation to be small and the same on each edge without having to adjust it over and over again, just draw the left polygon so that it overlaps the right one. Give each polygon the name of the assigned signal, and give the right polygon a higher rank. The polygon of the higher rank is drawn first, and the other polygon takes the area which is not covered by the first.

Comment: Note: highest rank means lowest number. 1 is higher ranked than 2